# jQuery Mobile: combine listview and checkbox fieldset

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile, I want to have a vertical list of items which the user can select by tapping on them.

I want:

1. a filter bar (so the user can first search for a subgroup of the items, and select among these)
2. no inset view (full width, no rounded corners)
3. a checkbox on right hand side which indicates whether the item is currently selected
4. full item surface activates the checkbox

This means to combine the behavior of a jQM thumbnail listview with filter (points 1. and 2. above) and a checkbox fieldset (points 3. and 4.).

My attemps so far fail with:
- a checkfox fieldset has no filter and is always inset
- listview does not show a jQM-styled checkbox, even when an `<input>` and a `<label>` item is used (as far as I can tell)

Any help is appreciated.

Using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzN7S/189/) example and add whatever you want to it. This is not your full requirement but it can be build upon.

This is original [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225883/checkbox-in-listview-with-jquery-mobile).

```
  <li data-icon="false">
     <div class="checkBoxLeft">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0"/>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="detailListText"> Message 1 </a>
  </li>
```

Now it is easy to create correlation between li element and its child checkbox.

To be able to activate/deactivate chechbox while interacting with li element us this code:

Long:

```
$('li').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false)    
    }  else {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)
    }
});
```

Short:

```
$('li').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) ? false : true);    
});
```

This should work on jQuery version 1.6 and above.

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thanks, this comes close. How should I make the checkbox active when the link <a> is clicked? How to use the jQM styled checkbox (currently the native one is used I presume)?

Comment: Take a look now, this can be also achieved with jQM styled checkbox but I dont have time to create such example.

Comment: This does not work on the windows phone 7/8 having IE9/10, what happens is that the list view click is not fired at the first time, it fires randomly and only when clicked on the right arrow icon it navigates to another page, rather behaves weird, works fine on android browsers. Any idea how to fix it?