# How to remove padding and border around input tag in listview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile I am trying to put a checkbox inside of a listview item. I want to remove the extra padding on the top/left/bottom as well as the rounded border. I wish to retain the right arrow of the anchor tag.

I managed to remove **some** of it by clearing the padding of the anchor tag. I have tried inspecting the elements in firefox and chrome but cannot figure out what is adding the space. It almost seems that the input tag is causing more padding of the parent.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Normal item</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" style="padding-top:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label ><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" />With Checkbox</label>
      </fieldset>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Normal item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/HPGGk/7/

**UPDATE**: I think I may be close. I determined the fieldset is adding the padding. I tweaked the margin and now I just need to remove the border: http://jsfiddle.net/HPGGk/8/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this examples, I made them few weeks ago for some else but they should work for you:

Example 1: Listview with classic check box:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13564924/1848600

Example 2: Listview with jQM look check box:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634738/1848600

Worst case scenario send me a msg and I will rebuild your example.

Comment: Example 2 is sort of what I am going for. It seems that you had to reimplement the jQM checkbox. Is that because of the problem that I described?

Comment: Yes it because of your problem, I needed a quick fix and this was it.

Comment: I think it may be possible with only css. I just posted an update to my question.